# Deeplink routing is not working as intended with multiple routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using `react-router-dom@^4` and I am trying to render some deeply routed components. Here is a simplified version of my `Base` component.

```
export default function Base() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/browse" component={Browser} />
      </Switch>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

This, in turn, will render the following component.

```
export default function Browser() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact component={ProjectPicker} />
      <Route exact path=":projectId" component={ProjectDetail} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

While the root (`/browse`) *does* work, when I navigate into `/browse/1` manually, it will fail. It essentially just renders nothing at all

Why is deeplinking failing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `/` in you path name

```
`<Route exact path="/:projectId" component={ProjectDetail} />`
```

see this official guide. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params